# I want to set lower_case_variables to 1 but I'm unable to locate my.cnf

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

MySQL was started with `service mysql start` only, but it is not showing the default path of my.cnf:

```
[root@localhost home]# ps -ef|grep mysql
root     23505     1  0 19:23 pts/4    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid
mysql    23596 23505  0 19:23 pts/4    00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid
root     23713 19420  0 19:49 pts/4    00:00:00 grep mysql
```

`my.cnf` is not under all our default locations.

When I start MySQL by creating a new `my.cnf` it does not start up.

I want to restart MySQL & add a variable in my.cnf.

When I remove `my.cnf` from `/etc`, MySQL is starting up with out any errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2485758/631764

Answer (score 0):

To locate all "my.cnf" in the system:

```
$ find / -name my.cnf
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are entering the variable under the proper heading. Check an example `my.cnf`, and you'll see that headings appear like this `[mysqld]`. If you don't put your directive under the correct heading, it won't work. I haven't heard of the variable you're talking about, but try putting it under "[mysqld]" like so:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_variables=1
```

Also check startup errors. You may find the variable name doesn't exist or some other error is in your config file.